# Клиент не запускается повторно

Tags: java

Имеется сервер и клиент.
Сервер может обрабатывать сразу несколько клиентов,но если клиенты закрываются,и заново подключаются то ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

```
package com.company;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ServerLoader {

  private static ServerSocket server;
  private static Map < Socket, ClietnHandler > handlers = new HashMap < > ();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    start();
    handle();
    end();
  }

  private static void handle() {
    int x = 5;
    while (true) {
      try {
        Socket client = server.accept();
        ClietnHandler handler = new ClietnHandler(client);
        handler.start();
        handlers.put(client, handler);
        System.out.println(server);
      } catch (SocketException ex) {
        // return;
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}


    }
  }

  public static void sendPacket(Socket receiver, String text) {
    try {
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(receiver.getOutputStream());
      dos.writeUTF(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public static void start() {
    try {
      server = new ServerSocket(8888);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static boolean isStarted() {
    return server != null && !server.isClosed();
  }
  public static void end() {
    System.out.println("Close");
    try {
      server.close();
      //   server = null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }


  public static ClietnHandler getHandler(Socket socket) {
    return handlers.get(socket);
  }

  public static void invalidate(Socket socket) {
    handlers.remove(socket);
  }
}
```

Клиент:

```
import packet.OPacket;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientLoader {

  private static Socket socket;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    connect();
    handle();

  }

  public static void sendPacket(OPacket packet) {
    try {

      ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      dos.writeObject(packet.getState());
      dos.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static Socket getSocket() {
    return socket;
  }
  public static void connect() {
    try {
      socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
      System.out.println(socket);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void handle() {
    TextFieldTest p = new TextFieldTest();
  }

  public static void end() {
    try {
      System.out.println("close clbent");
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: вы пробовали нажать на кнопочку `выполнить код`?

Comment: прект большой,выложил только по файлу

Comment: Так нам самим надо догадаться как реализованы отсутствующие классы?

Comment: Где-то я видел пример, который использует многопоточность.